# Cannot retrieve directory listing from vsftpd after enabling TLS

Tags: server, ftp, vsftpd, openssl, tls

I set up vsftpd on an Ubuntu 16.04 server. I added a user, and gave him FTP access via a userlist and chrooted him to his home directory. It worked fine. To make the file transfer more secure I wanted to add a TLS connection.

I created a new certificate with OpenSSL:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem -out /etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

and adapted my `vsftpd.conf`:

```
ssl_enable=YES
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
```

After restarting vsftpd and trying to connect via FileZilla or WinSCP I got the prompt to accept the certificate. But both programs do not actually connect me to the server. They "stop" at "retrieve-directory-listing". This is what happens when I try to log in using FileZilla:

```
Status: Resolving address of **
Status: Connecting to [**]:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    EPSV
Response:   229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||13468|)
Command:    LIST
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Status: Disconnected from server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't open the data connection ports in your firewall.

It may work without the encryption, if the [firewall is smart and opens the ports automatically](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes#smart) *(link to my article)* by inspecting the FTP control connection. But when the control connection is encrypted, the firewall cannot inspect it.

The data connection port range is set in your [`vsftpd.conf`](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/vsftpd_conf.html) by `pasv_max_port` and `pasv_min_port` directives.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you very much for your help! I added `pasv_enable=Yes
pasv_max_port=50000
pasv_min_port=40000` and opened the ports using ufw `sudo ufw allow 40000:50000/tcp`